# output can compile 

Tags: c++

I can't seem to get this code to run and I need to know the output. Can some one please help me?

```
vector<int> myinventory(4);
myinventory[0] = 2;
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    myinventory[i] = 2*myinventory[i -1];
}
myinventory.push_back(34);
for (int i = 0; i < myinventory.size(); i++)
{
    cout << myinventory[i]<< " ";
}
```

Please, if you can provide the output that would be great.

Comment: Write it, compile it, run it. Period.

Comment: If that's the entirety of your code, you're missing some `#include` statements, and a `main` function.

Comment: Do I look like a compiler to you?

Comment: do you seriously want the question to the answer?

Comment: this is the main body of the program ...

Comment: ofcourse i have #include <iostream>

Comment: @Wayne: So what you posted is not your whole code? You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: using namespace std;   int main()  ect.... but it wont compile

Comment: The next time you ask a question like this, at least post the errors you're getting.

Comment: @wayne - Bart is right - you had to post the whole code and provide us the errors. We need to see, that you've tried something..I guess you've missed `#include <vector>`, btw.

Comment: @wayne - Welcome to Stackoverflow. You need to post the error message too along with small compilable code that reproduce this error. With that said, have you included `vector` header. `#include <vector>`.

Comment: If it doesn't compile, there is no output.  If your compiler is broken, [try this](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: @Wayne: If you walked to a car repair shop and said "my car is broken" and they said "ok, let's take a look" and you said "here are the keys, I didn't bring the car", how do you think they'd look at you? You need to show us your entire program, how you're compiling it, what you expected, and what you got instead. All of it.

Comment: @GMan That was a good metaphor.

Comment: @wayne - Apply what GMan suggested to your question. I will vote to reopen it :)

Comment: @wayne And I'll be glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just walk through it on pen and paper. Or as already said; write it, compile and run.

Answer (score 1):

Try `cout << myinventory[i]<< " " << std::endl;`

to flush the console output.  Hard to tell if this will work since "it won't run" is not hugely informative.  Have you tried stepping through itin the debugger?